# RabbitMQ - How do I send fanout style message that is processed by only one of a group of consumers and all consumers outside the group

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

I am fairly new to rabbitMQ and wondering how I can setup the system to best suit my needs.

Assuming I have 5 consumer processes (C1-5) and C1-3 only require **one** of them to consume that message. C4 and C5 **also** need to receive the message.

How can I configure rabbitMQ to achieve this?

[image: Diagram of system]
I have considered popping another consumer in front of C1-3 to simply push to a standard queue and C1-3 will consume from that but I am wondering if this is additional work and rabbitMQ has a better way to solve this issue?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Fab

Comment: Your diagram is exactly how rabbit works, it should work out great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough to do, just have C1-C3 attach to the same queue. There's no need for an additional consumer/publisher route.

---

### Example:

*(Using PHP and [videlalvaro/php-amqplib](https://packagist.org/packages/videlalvaro/php-amqplib)*.)

#### send.php

Declare the fanout exchange *"events"* and publish messages to it.

```php
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$exchange = 'events';

$connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'fanout', false, false, false);

$data = implode(' ', array_slice($argv, 1));
if(empty($data)) $data = "Something happened!";
$msg = new AMQPMessage($data);

$channel->basic_publish($msg, $exchange);

echo " [x] Sent ", $data, "\n";

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

---

#### pooledreceive.php *(C1-C3)*

Attach to a named *"pool"* queue. Messages will get distributed among receivers.

```php
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;

$exchange = 'events';
$queue = 'pool';

$connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'fanout', false, false, false);
$channel->queue_declare($queue);
$channel->queue_bind($queue, $exchange);

echo ' [*] Waiting for events. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

$callback = function($msg) {
    echo ' [x] ', $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume($queue, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

---

#### receive.php *(C4, C5)*

Each of these receivers get their own queue and own copy of the message.

```php
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;

$exchange = 'events';

$connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'fanout', false, false, false);

list($queue_name, ,) = $channel->queue_declare('');

$channel->queue_bind($queue_name, $exchange);

echo ' [*] Waiting for events. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

$callback = function($msg) {
    echo ' [x] ', $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume($queue_name, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```